# Control for showing multiline content in inno set up installer

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I want to show the content like in below image in installation step of installer...i have used memo for showing the content..but memo is not appropriate control..as then it looks like a textbox if user puts focus on the memo field... see  below image.. when user comes to this step,the first memo field is selected...[image: installation type]

Comment: Use `TLabel` or `TNewStaticText` and set them `WordWrap` to True and `AutoSize` to False.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use either [`TLabel`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TLabel) or [`TNewStaticText`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewStaticText) component (the [`TNewStaticText`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewStaticText) seems to be preferred inside of InnoSetup) and set it the following:

- the `WordWrap` property to `True`
- the `AutoSize` property to `False`

Then just stretch the components into your desired positions and the text will fit to that bounds, just like shown in this example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]    
const
  LoremIpsum =
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mauris ' +
    'lorem, ullamcorper sit amet tincidunt ac, varius at ante. Aenean pretium, ' +
    'tortor non congue pharetra, ante urna consectetur mi, vitae congue arcu est ' +
    'eleifend nisl.';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
  StandardDescLabel: TLabel;
  StandardRadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
  AdvancedDescLabel: TLabel;
  AdvancedRadioButton: TNewRadioButton;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Installation type', '');
  StandardRadioButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  StandardRadioButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  StandardRadioButton.Checked := True;
  StandardRadioButton.Top := 16;
  StandardRadioButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  StandardRadioButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  StandardRadioButton.Font.Size := 9;
  StandardRadioButton.Caption := 'Standard Installation'
  StandardDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  StandardDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  StandardDescLabel.Left := 8;
  StandardDescLabel.Top := StandardRadioButton.Top + StandardRadioButton.Height + 8;
  StandardDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth; 
  StandardDescLabel.Height := 40;
  StandardDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  StandardDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  StandardDescLabel.Caption := LoremIpsum;
  AdvancedRadioButton := TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  AdvancedRadioButton.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  AdvancedRadioButton.Top := StandardDescLabel.Top + StandardDescLabel.Height + 16;
  AdvancedRadioButton.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  AdvancedRadioButton.Font.Style := [fsBold];
  AdvancedRadioButton.Font.Size := 9;
  AdvancedRadioButton.Caption := 'Advanced Installation'
  AdvancedDescLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  AdvancedDescLabel.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Left := 8;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Top := AdvancedRadioButton.Top + AdvancedRadioButton.Height + 8;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Width := CustomPage.SurfaceWidth;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Height := 40;
  AdvancedDescLabel.AutoSize := False;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Wordwrap := True;
  AdvancedDescLabel.Caption := LoremIpsum;
end;
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Setting `AutoSize` to `False` is unnecessary according to [the docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/StdCtrls_TLabel_AutoSize.html). And I just tested it and it seems to work fine with `AutoSize` on `True`.

Comment: @Ignitor, I would keep it there. Just this is the case when the label should be autosized. As it's mentioned in docs, *"the size of the label readjusts whenever the text changes"* and I'm changing it, don't I ?

Comment: Well, the question is what is desired: if you don't want the label to automatically adjusts **it's height**, then you set `AutoSize` to `False`. Even with `AutoSize := True;`, the label will __not adjust it's width__ when `WordWarp` is enabled. However, I mainly wanted to point out that **it is not necessary to set `AutoSize := False` for `WordWrap := True` to work**.

Comment: I struggled a bit before I realized that you have to set `WordWrap` _before_ setting `Caption`. Otherwise there's no multiline for you.