# Inno Setup wizard page for toolbar installer

Tags: inno-setup

Attempting to create an install with a page similar to this using the components wizard page with text similar to this
! [page style] http://grahamskaraokesystem.com/toolbar.png

I can put mulitlines in the toolbar description but then the check mark is centered on the description text. I also can't seem to figure out how to bold the text in the description.

I've come a long way with stackoverflow help but I have got a long, long way to go.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should this be a custom page or a separate window ? Also, should there be some logic behind (e.g. those check boxes disabled when the first radio button is selected) ?

Comment: @TLama The Quick (Recommended) install would incorporate all components which is basically my program install plus a one line hidden executable with switches that installs all components of the toolbar.  The advanced mode will allow the install of my program as well as some or none of the toolbar.  The actual install of the toolbar uses the same exe as the quick (or full) installation with switches being turned off depending on what the user desires to do.  I originally used a text box below the components selected to indicate that quick would install all but the offer was not clear.

Comment: I tried to insert my script but I could not get it to work this time.  If it helps you can download the script from [link]http://grahamskaraokesystem.com/script.iss

Comment: Also I forgot to add when the first button is selected then all other boxes would be disabled.  When advanced box is selected then I should be able to check or uncheck the next two boxes and the first button should be disabled.  I can do the logic to get the install procedures working but what I cannot figure out is how to put the first button at the top of the comment as opposed to centered within the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

@Tlama I found the answer from one of your other excellent explanations at [Control for showing multiline content in inno set up installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718831/control-for-showing-multiline-content-in-inno-set-up-installer)